# Maxwell‘s equations for two waves shifted by a quarter of wavelength

Tags: physics, wave-equation

What would Maxwell's equations

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{E} &= \frac{\partial \, \boldsymbol{B}}{\partial \, t}, 
&\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{B} &= -\,\frac{\partial \, \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial \, t}.
\end{align}

have to look like to correspond to the following sketch and the two wave equations?

[image]
The sketch shows two wave functions with $\boldsymbol{B}$ shifted by a quarter of a wavelenght.

\begin{align}\boldsymbol{E}(t, x) &= \boldsymbol{a} \sin{(k \, x - \omega \, t + \phi)} \\[3pt]
\boldsymbol{B}(t, x) &= \boldsymbol{b} \cos{(k \, x - \omega \, t + \phi)}
\end{align}

The question came to mind after reading this question about [Non-standard representation of the free electromagnetic plane wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237146/non-standard-representation-of-the-free-electromagnetic-plane-wave).

Comment: Are you looking for a system of PDE's that are as close to Maxwell's equations as in a vacuum as possible (in some sense or another) but that has the form you wrote down as a solution?

Comment: @doetoe Perfect. That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\underline{\text{Modifying Maxwell's equations}}$

Consider the $\color{red}{\text{modifications}}$ to Faraday's law and Ampere's law $^\dagger$

$$
\nabla \times E = \color{red}{-i}\partial_t B \qquad ; \qquad \nabla \times B = -\color{red}{i}\partial_t E
$$

The wave equations for $E$ and $B$ follow as usual by taking the curl of each equation and appealing to Gauss' laws $\nabla \cdot E=0$ and $\nabla \cdot B=0$

$$
\nabla^2E=\partial_{tt}E \qquad ; \qquad \nabla^2B=\partial_{tt}B
$$

Which admit plane wave solutions. Consider the particular solutions

$$
E(z,t)=E_0e^{i(kz-\omega t)} \hat{x} \\
B(z,t)=B_0e^{i(kz-\omega t)} \hat{y} \tag{1}
$$

Using "Faraday's law" we find the relation between $E_0$ and $B_0$

$$
B_0=\frac{ik}{\omega}E_0
$$

From "Ampere's law" we learn that $|\omega|=|k|$. Noting that $i=e^{i\pi/2}$ (and with $\omega$ and $k$ real) we have

$$
B(z,t)=E_0 e^{i(kz-\omega t+\pi/2)} \hat{y}
$$

So $B$ is exactly $\pi/2$ out of phase with $E$, as necessary.

$\dagger$ It is amusing that these look very nearly like a Wick rotation.

$\underline{\text{Without modifying Maxwell's equations}}$

In a conductor, with a current density given by $J=\sigma E$, we can again take the curl of Faraday's law and Ampere's law to get damped wave equations for $E$ and $B$

$$
\nabla^2E=\sigma \partial_t E+\partial_{tt}E \qquad ; \qquad \nabla^2B=\sigma \partial_t B+\partial_{tt}B
$$

These admit solutions of the form (1) except that $k \in \mathbb{C}$ such that

$$
k^2=\omega^2+i \sigma \omega
$$

Substituting into Faraday's law yields

$$
B_0=\frac{k}{\omega}E_0=\frac{|k|e^{i\phi}}{\omega}E_0
$$

After a little algebra, we find that the phase difference $\phi$ between $E$ and $B$ is given by

$$
\phi=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\sigma}{\omega} \right)
$$

This is nice, but the solutions with complex $k$ are not free waves, they are damped exponentials, for instance

$$
E(z,t)=E_0e^{-k_I z}e^{i(k_R z-\omega t)}
$$

Where $k_R$ and $k_I$ are the real and imaginary parts of $k$.

Comment: Sal thank you for your answer. I suppose that $\frac{\partial \, \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial \, t}$ the same as $-i\partial_t E$?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I'm just using the notation $\frac{ \partial E}{\partial t}=\partial_t E$. The modification to Maxwell's equations consists of the multiplication by $\pm i$ on the RHS of Faraday's and Ampere's law

Comment: Excuse me for an additional clarification: Why do physicists insist that such a solution is not applicable to radio waves?

Comment: I am not sure about radio waves *specifically*, but in general such a solution (with a phase difference) simply doesn't satisfy Faraday's or Ampere's law in free space, as we can verify by direct substitution